# JavaScript scrolling page without anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find if there's any solution related to scrolling the page like fullpage.js does. Scrolling a website page by page, down and up.

This is different to fullpage.js as it slides the page to different a div, but I need it move in a single div.

Here's the code I tried:

```
<div> a very long text here..... </div>

Window.onscroll = function() {test()};

Function test(){ window.scrollby(0, 300) };
```

The code above only scrolls down and it doesn't stop. It scrolls all the way down until the bottom of the page.

So, how?

Comment: >This is different to fullpage.js as it slides the page to different a div, but I need it move in a single div. You need to move within a div? Ok, by how much?

Comment: the problem is your starting an infinity recursive loop. here is what happens, when you scroll down(or up) windows.onscroll calls test. test tells the browser to scroll down 300 pixel... but when test tell the browser to scroll, it  triggers windows.onscroll which calls test again, and since test once again tell it to scroll down, it trigger windows.onscroll which call test again, it does this for ever.

Comment: Oh. Yep. I saw it. So how i am going to do that? I am using fullpage.js before, you may check here jommarketing.com/mbjb1/page.php .. you can see the words are in other div, so if my device height and width is bigger, the page will looks like empty.

Comment: @zer00ne maybe some 300 pixel going down everytime we scroll

Comment: I answered before you replied @MrHery

Comment: I believe the concept of `div` you have is kinda funny...
You might want to check the [`fp-auto-height` feature of fullpage.js](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1259/).

Comment: @Alvaro. Wow. I am quite shock that you reply my post. Your fullpage js is very great, only i has no exeperience with it. Btw sir, i have tried the fp-auto-height, but its doesnt work for me. Erm,

Answer (score 0):

You need something to stop the infinite loop, try this...

```
<div> a very long text here..... </div>

Window.onscroll = function() {test()};
var isAutoScroll = false;
Function test(){ 
if(!isAutoScroll ){
   isAutoScroll = true;//Next time will not scroll
   window.scrollby(0, 300) };
}
else
{
   isAutoScroll = false;
   return;
}
```

Comment: Hi sir. I read about it, but its for click function. I seeking for scroll fucntion

Comment: Just put this in a function, and call it from where ever you want, it will scroll regardless if its from a click or not..

Comment: Sorry sir, i still dont get it. I have put given code in my function, what it does is, its scrolling by itself down to 600 px whenever i refresh page, and its stop. And if i scroll the mouse, its not going to another 600 px. Hopefully you get what i mean. You may check my simulator at jommarketing.com/mbjb1/page.php .

Comment: Nice sir. Its work. But how do i can make going up back? Hehe. I really wish to pay for this code with effective cost at the end of this project ☺.